# Mailkit - no attachments or html body when receiving message sent from apple mail

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

I have been using Mailkit library to receive emails and so far it has been great. However, we found a problem with messages that are sent via Mail app on Mac. For instance, a message that we sent with a pdf attachment and html-formatted body, is being received (throgh IMailFolder.GetMessage) as an object without any attachments and only HtmlBody being null (only TextBody is received)

I am attaching sourcecode of this mail (without some personal information headers) from a web email client (the message is displayed ok there)

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="Apple-Mail=_CA0BDF81-AE2A-4E1A-9D37-8B30B5220C77"
Subject: Test
Date: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 07:00:29 -0700
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 8.0 \(1990.1\))
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1990.1)


--Apple-Mail=_CA0BDF81-AE2A-4E1A-9D37-8B30B5220C77
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=us-ascii


Hello goodbye pdf

--Apple-Mail=_CA0BDF81-AE2A-4E1A-9D37-8B30B5220C77
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="Apple-Mail=_FA44F8C6-5F68-44EF-9537-8E8651DAAC0C"


--Apple-Mail=_FA44F8C6-5F68-44EF-9537-8E8651DAAC0C
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset=us-ascii

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=us-ascii"></head><body style="word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;" class=""><div class=""><br class=""></div><div class=""><b class=""><i class="">Hello</i></b></div><div class=""><b class=""><i class="">goodbye pdf</i></b></div></body></html>
--Apple-Mail=_FA44F8C6-5F68-44EF-9537-8E8651DAAC0C
Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename*=utf-8''Zamo%CC%81wienie%20ZAM21%2D150528%2D01.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf;
    x-unix-mode=0644;
    name="=?utf-8?Q?Zamo=CC=81wienie_ZAM21-150528-01=2Epdf?="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

(here is a base64-encoded pdf that is being decoded correctly)
--Apple-Mail=_FA44F8C6-5F68-44EF-9537-8E8651DAAC0C
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset=us-ascii

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=us-ascii"></head><body style="word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;" class=""></body></html>
--Apple-Mail=_FA44F8C6-5F68-44EF-9537-8E8651DAAC0C--

--Apple-Mail=_CA0BDF81-AE2A-4E1A-9D37-8B30B5220C77--
```

Has anyone faced this kind of problem with Mailkit? Or maybe it isn't library-dependant, just specific apple mail?

Comment: Is that actually how the raw message looks? There wasn't a paste error that accidentally removed line breaks before the Content-Type and Content-Transfer-Encoding headers?

Comment: yes indeed the line breaks should be there, they're ok in the source view of the mail, sorry for that

Comment: @matt137 how do you look for text and attachment for apple emails, im facing same issue. I look for htmlbody or texbody. is there a short way to sort this out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MimeMessage.TextBody and MimeMessage.HtmlBody properties are convenience properties that use common practices to determine what the appropriate text body parts of the message are. Unfortunately, there is no strict definition of "this 1 part and 1 part only is the text body, and this other 1 part is the html body".

The structure of this message is as follows:

```
multipart/alternative
  text/plain
  multipart/mixed
    text/html
    application/pdf
    text/html
```

Normally, in a `multipart/alternative`, you'll have 1 of the following 2 cases:

```
multipart/alternative
  text/plain
  text/html
```

or

```
multipart/alternative
  text/plain
  multipart/related
    text/html
    application/pdf
```

The `multipart/alternative` defines alternative views (I know, I'm stating the obvious here). MimeKit finds the `text/plain` part because it follows the general conventions. But the next alternative is a `multipart/mixed`. That's not HTML, so MimeKit cannot return it as the `HtmlBody`. MimeKit's logic for determining the `HtmlBody` only understands `multipart/related` inside of a `multipart/alternative` because the spec for `multipart/related` defines which part is the root document (which is generally an HTML document).

In the case of your message, what this means is that the `multipart/mixed` *is* your alternate view and the sending agent intended for those 3 parts to be rendered in sequence as the alternate message body. You can't really just pick one of those 2 html parts and use it as the html body because it would be incomplete without the other (and without the pdf).

That said, MimeKit does not limit you to the use of the `TextBody` and `HtmlBody` properties to get your message body. MimeKit provides a number of ways to iterate over the MIME structure yourself to use your own logic to get what you need.

Refer to the following documentation:

[FAQ / MessageBody](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Frequently-Asked-Questions.htm#MessageBody)

[Working With Messages](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the answear, especialy for clarifying the structure of this message, which I was unable to. And with the help of the second articIe I managed to implement code that is not as dependant on HtmlBody and TextBody fields now as it was before

Comment: Excellent! Glad I was able to help!

Comment: @jstedfast i have an apple email in which i dont get email content in textbody or html body and i if i traverse throught textpart in bodypart, i get 2 text/plain, do i have to concat the text in it. will it always contain email content?

Comment: This is the question that all mail client developers eventually face and the must decide that on their own. There are no hard and fast rules to make that decision.

Comment: Usually the first one is the message body and any others are text attachments, but depending on the mailer, it might expect you to concatenation.

Comment: You mentioned that "MimeKit's logic for determining the HtmlBody only understands multipart/related inside of a multipart/alternative because the spec for multipart/related defines which part is the root document (which is generally an HTML document)." I found an instance where the html part inside the related but mailkit returns a null. Here is the link to the .eml file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg2p93skiqywfp7/1.eml?dl=0. Wondering if I made a mistake in creating this email from mimekit.

Comment: In your sample message, the first part of the multipart/related is a png image. If the multipart/related does not define which of its children is the root document, then the first MIME part is assumed to be the root document. Since the root document is the png, then the HTML part is assumed to be referenced somehow by the root document. MailKit is doing the right thing here.

Comment: If you created this message in MimeKit, then you need to make sure to add the HTML part to the multipart/related first or else set it by using the `MultipartRelated.Root` property.

Comment: Yes, when I changed the location to the htmlpart to the beginning of the related, it worked just fine. Also checked RFC2387 section 3.1 it says what you are saying. Thanks a lot.